# iScroll4 - disable click events while scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, iscroll4

im using iSroll4 on a div that has Lis inside it, and each LI has a link.
when i start scrolling the click events of the inner LIs is triggered.
i want the click events to keep available but not while scrolling.

help please..
thnx :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
  if (myScroll.moved) return; 
  // add click functionality here
});
```

From iScroll forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iscroll/0ai6QzTtbJE